# Migrating an App to High-Replication Datastore - now ancestor issues

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Following these instructions:
http://neogregious.blogspot.com/2011/04/migrating-app-to-high-replication.html

I have managed to migrate to the high replication datastore however I am now getting the following exception:

```
datastore_errors.BadArgumentError('ancestor argument should match app ("%r" != "%r")' %
        (ancestor.app(), app))
```

The model data looks something like this:

```
class base_business(polymodel.PolyModel):
  created = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)

class business(base_business):
  some_data = db.StringProperty()
  etc..

class business_image(db.Model):
  image = db.BlobProperty(default=None)
  mimetype = db.StringProperty()
  comment = db.StringProperty(required=False)

# the image is associated like so
image_item = business_image(parent = business_item, etc... )
image_item.put()
```

The new app name has not been assigned to the ancestor model data. At the moment the data is returned however the logs are being populated with this exception message.

The actual stack trace using logging.exception:

> 2011-11-03 16:45:40.211
>   ======= get_business_image exception [ancestor argument should match app ("'oldappname'" != "'s~newappname'")] ======= 
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/base/data/home/apps/s~newappname/3.354412961756003398/oldappname/entities/views.py", line 82, in get_business_image
>       business_img = business_image.gql("WHERE ANCESTOR IS :ref_business and is_primary = True", ref_business = db.Key(business_key)).get()
>     File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/db/**init**.py", line 2049, in get
>       results = self.fetch(1, config=config)
>     File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/db/**init**.py", line 2102, in fetch
>       raw = raw_query.Get(limit, offset, config=config)
>     File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/datastore.py", line 1668, in Get
>       config=config, limit=limit, offset=offset, prefetch_size=limit))
>     File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/datastore.py", line 1600, in GetBatcher
>       return self.GetQuery().run(_GetConnection(), query_options)
>     File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/datastore.py", line 1507, in GetQuery
>       order=self.GetOrder())
>     File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py", line 93, in positional_wrapper
>       return wrapped(*args, **kwds)
>     File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_query.py", line 1722, in **init**
>       ancestor=ancestor)
>     File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py", line 93, in positional_wrapper
>       return wrapped(*args, **kwds)
>     File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_query.py", line 1561, in **init**
>       (ancestor.app(), app))
>   BadArgumentError: ancestor argument should match app ("'oldappname'" != "'s~newappname'")

Is there a way to manually set the app on the model data?  Could I do something like this to resolve this?

```
if( ancestor.app() != app )
  set_app('my_app')
  put()
```

Before I do this or apply any other HACK is there something I should have done as part of the data migration?

Comment: Where's the code? And where's the complete stacktrace?

Comment: Is that the complete error message? It looks like it's in a function you wrote yourself, and it seems likely you're suppressing an actual exception and logging just that. Can you modify it to log the original stacktrace? (Just use logging.exception instead of logging.error).

Comment: Added logging.exception and the resulting exception detail in the body above.

Comment: I think I have worked out what is going on from the stacktrace, the images are being requested by facebook and google with the previous image key which would contain the previous application name.  Which would also explain why it is not appearing in the logs when I am just browsing the site.  It will only occur when searching on google (maybe just images) or within the previews in facebook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sort of error usually occurs because you're using fully qualified keys somewhere that have been stored in the datastore as strings (instead of ReferenceProperty), or outside the datastore, such as in URLs. You should be able to work around this by reconstructing any keys from external sources such that you ignore the App ID, something like this:

```
my_key = db.Key.from_path(*db.Key(my_key).to_path())
```

Comment: Awesome that works.  Thanks again for your great developer support :)

Comment: Interesting solution. I didn't face this problem myself but it helps me understand how GAE works. Thank you Google and Nick J for being so good with information and pedagogical. It is very positive that a comporation as large as Google can deliver such a good product as app engine when looking at the billion-dollar companies nowadays it is not the billion-dollar companies that deliver the best technology where Google is an exception: A billion-dollar company that also deliver the best technical solution while otherwise we must search at smaller technical specialized providers.